# Call Java-Methods in browser

Tags: java, html, web

my main Problem I is that I'm new to this topic and don't know how to successfully google it.

I have a Java-program up and running which is just console-based (no GUI). I want to have a browser interface for it. I want to know how to:

- Make a Link on a HTML-Page so that it calls a method in the java-program when clicked
- print text from the java-program to the Html Page
- enter Strings in a Input field and pass them to the java program

Simple exaample: A simple page with one input field, one "submit"-button and one text field. I enter a name, press submit, the java code gets the string, manipulates it, passes it back to the html page where it is displayed.

The question might seem simple but I need a place to start. Any tutorial link would be very welcomed.

Cheers

Comment: https://www.google.co.in/search?q=java+form+servlet+html&oq=java+form+servlet+html&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.4503j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8#q=servlet+and+html+form+

Comment: http://www.journaldev.com/1854/java-web-application-tutorial-for-beginners

Comment: Thats what servlets are good for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google for *Java Servlet programming for beginners*

couple resources:

http://www.journaldev.com/1877/java-servlet-tutorial-with-examples-for-beginners

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tkFRGdUgCsE

I strongly recommend to study Java 2 Standard Edition before dealing with servlets.

You need to deeply understand how does the core java work, and only then approach to more complex technologies.

Good luck.

Comment: Thank you I'll look into all of this and try my best.